# Position a element that goes off the side?

Tags: css, html, alignment, centering, start-page

I am trying to make the "FlowerPot" text to center-align, but it will not work. I don't know why. Maybe it is the `<code>` element that makes it all crazy, but I don't think that would make a difference. This is my code:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two:400,400italic);
 body {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #B10DC9;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  right: 0;
}
img {
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: 0;
  float: left;
}
code {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  z-index: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
#introdiv {
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="introdiv">
  <img src="http://cakestyle.tv/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Flower-Pot-no-background-smaller.png"></img>
  <code style="font-family:Lobster Two; font-size:60px;">FlowerPot</code>
</div>
```

Please help. I don't know what I am doing wrong. DO I need to add or delete something? DO I need to change anything?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: add `left: 0;` to `code` - http://jsfiddle.net/zq0yjpzp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `left:0` to `code`

```
code {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  z-index: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

modify selector `code` style and add `left: 0;` style. you can get your result.